# combine data from selected sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that has a lot of sheets of data grouped by category. I have a main sheet that I want a user to be able to choose which categories of data to use, and it will pull that data into one long list.

Here is an example spreadsheet of what I want to do: [LINK TO SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1et1M_JZ8b9RdKXWMixzUJYyEBS6SNa_RSWrfWu_m3zQ/edit?usp=sharing)

I could combine all the data into one spreadsheet, but if I were to do that with the dataset I am working with, I would have tens of thousands of rows. So, having the data stored on separate sheets is preferred. I am open to having separate spreadsheets altogether if that will make it easier. Currently, I have tried Using INDIRECT and QUERY, but can only get the first sheet of data to show.

I would prefer to stick to normal functions, but could jump into appscript if I need to create a custom formula

I have tried using INDIRECT and CONCAT, and can get the first set of data, but not subsequent data. Also tried wrapping it in a query like this:
`=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(CONCAT(A2:A,"!a2:z100"))},"select * where Col1 is not null",1))`

Splitting it up into separate spreadsheets, I was able to use the function:
`=QUERY({ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE(B2:B,"A1:Z10"))},"select * where Col1 is not null",1)`
But it also would only pull the first set of data, not the subsequent rows.

All of this was me first attempting to get the information, not getting the information filtered by the sheets that were checked as well. I am pretty familiar with appscript as well and open to appscript solutions, but would prefer to stay away from it if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need additional column. Use `REDUCE()` with few other formula-

```
=REDUCE(HSTACK("Dataset Name","Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4"),FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=TRUE),
LAMBDA(x,y,VSTACK(x,QUERY(INDIRECT(y&"!A2:E"),"where A is not null"))))
```

[image]

Comment: If `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` isn't available to your region then try- `=REDUCE({"Dataset Name","Data 1","Data 2","Data 3","Data 4"},FILTER(A2:A,B2:B=TRUE),LAMBDA(x,y,{x;QUERY(INDIRECT(y&"!A2:E"),"where A is not null")}))`.